# How to get spinner value without tag

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm using the spinner, and I want to get the text selected for the user so I'm using

```
String datacat = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

the problem is that this sentence also return the tag of the spinner in a String like this: `{supplier=VITA}`, but I need to get only the `VITA` value

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947933/how-to-get-spinner-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming selectedview is EditText.

```
String datacat =((EditText) categorySpinner.getSelectedView()).getText().toString();
```

Comment: getText is nos a valid method for getSelectedView or getSelectedItem

Comment: see my updated answer. Again, assuming your view is EditText, otherwise you will get ClassCastException.

Comment: is a spinner not a EditText I got the ClassCastException

I'm trying to get the text of the item selected on the spinner view

Comment: Spinner is not edittext, spinner may have edittext. Did you try solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner-android

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String datacat = categorySpinner.getSelectedView().getText().toString()
```

you may have to cast the view before you can call getText()

Comment: getText is not a valid method  for getSelectedview or getselecteditem