# Android Compare two spinner and intent to new activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

i have and activity it has two spinner....

example:  1st spinner has *india *pakistan *bangladesh
2nd spinner has *india *pakistan *bangladesh

when we select 1st spinner bangladesh and 2nd spinner india and then click submit it must be go to a new activity call BDTOINDActivity.java

when we select 1st spinner bangladesh and 2nd spinner Pakistan and then click submit it must be go to a new activity call BDTOIPAKActivity.java

Comment: Sabbir, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //First get the selected country name
           String sp1Val = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String sp2Val = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

           // Then compare both spinner values:
          if(sp1Value.equals("Bangladesh") && sp2Val.equals("India")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BDTOINDActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
          }

           //Do the rest of them as same
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it Works tnx bro :)

Comment: Anytime!  Guess what, I have also studied in Sylhet, from SUST ;)

Comment: ow that's great.  I am now studying CSE at Metropolitan University.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Good luck with your study. If any help needed, don't forget to question. Help is always available here. :)

Comment: Rupam vai can u solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929640/android-download-image-from-jason-url-but-its-not-working-but-when-i-insertd-sdc

Comment: @sabbirahmed darao dekhtesi

Answer (score 1):

it is simple to compare to value of spinners
So look at this useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856029/7699710

and also i paste the code here:

```
Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String txtFromSpinner1 = mySpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
String txtFromSpinner2 = mySpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

after defining this spinners do this:

```
if (txtFromSpinner1.equals(txtFromSpinner2))
{
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
   CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: i dont get it clearly . i want my 1st spinner value compare to 2nd spinner and then intent to a new activity.. i am new can u plz provie this code? example: 1st spinner has *india *pakistan *bangladesh 2nd spinner has *india *pakistan *bangladesh

when we select 1st spinner bangladesh and 2nd spinner india and then click submit it must be go to a new activity call BDTOINDActivity.class

when we select 1st spinner bangladesh and 2nd spinner Pakistan and then click submit it must be go to a new activity call BDTOIPAKActivity.class

Comment: ok answer has updated.

Answer (score 0):

Get spinner's values, create full activity class name and start activity.

```
//activity field
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

//onCreate
map.put("india", "IND");
map.put("pakistan", "PAK");
map.put("bangladesh", "BD");


//on submit
String fromStr = fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String toStr = toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

String packagePrefix = "our.package.name.";

String activityName = packagePrefix + map.get(fromStr) + "TO" + map.get(toStr)  + "Activity";
Class<?> activityClass = null;
try {
    activityClass = Class.forName(activityName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
startActivity(intent);
```