# Android getting selected spinner text

Tags: android

I am trying to get the selected item from a spinner, I want to then store this item into an array but at the moment I am just wondering how I can get the current selected item. Below is my current spinner code I have many spinners within the class.

```
Spinner session = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSession);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSession = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.session_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSession.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    session.setAdapter(adapterSession);
```

this spinner binds to an array defined within my strings file. So all I want it to get the item selected by the user.

thanks

Comment: Check out this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This is straight from the developer docs at:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Basically you need to implement an onItemSelectedListener for the spinner.