# Android spinner position and if statements

Tags: android, if-statement, spinner

Having an odd issue here and don't know why it doesn't work, I'm not that used to java yet.
to determine the selected item what needs to be done?
the spinner has 8 items and 'position' never = 1, or any other number.
`onItemSelected()` is definitely getting fired so is the if statement wrong?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {

    if (position == 1) //do something
}
```

EDIT:
thanks Lion
it turns out position doesnt seem to do anything. however, this works.

```
String s = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (s == "1")//do something
```

Comment: "*I'm not that used to java yet*", really? then you need to spend some time to it before you start with Android projects.

Comment: thanks for the help lol. you see something wrong or not? you mind pointing it out?

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code. Therefore, I can't answer in its entirely but you may refer to these questions. [How do you get the selected value of a spinner — Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner-android), [Get spinner selected items text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text), [Android Spinner: Get the selected item change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event). Hope these questions and answers help you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the proper listener for the spinner.

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              if (position == 1){
                 //Do something}
              }
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                  // Do nothing.
      }           
 });
```

If you're "not that used to Java" I recommend you read some basics.

Comment: thanks, i can manage that much, i dont dabble in java often but spend my life programming in other languages.

Comment: You're welcome. If you know other OO languages then Java would be piece of cake for you ;)
Accept my answer if it works for you, please.