# how to retrieve the selected value from spinner and use it in another class? - Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

as demonstrated here by jalopaba, I already created a new class: [How do you get the selected value of a Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner-android)

```
public class MyItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

and registering this to the spinner in the original class:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

However, I still can't use that selected string yet to fill in my code in the same class:

```
textView.setText(selected);
```

I'm new to this Android anyway, so this question may be too dummy to some of you

Comment: Initalize the string variable out side the class . Initialize it in main class above onCreate() Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the setText code in the onItemSelected:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    yourTextView.setText(parent.getSelectedItem().toString);
}
```

Comment: this won't work, my textView isn't registered in this MyItemSelectedListener class

Comment: Have you initialised your TextView like `yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(<textview id>);` ??

Comment: And make sure that the TextView is Global, Declare it outside all methods and initialise it in onCreate.

Comment: you gave me an idea, I double declared TextView in every class that can modify the value of TextView itself, works like magic!

Comment: so you mean to say there is no way i can use that string outside of `onItemSelected`?? I have tried deca;ring the string as global but as soon as I try to use it in my other methods I get a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,I hope It's help you.

```
final CharSequence[] array_min = {"No 

  Min","100","200","300","400", "500","600","700","800","900","1000",
                  "1100","1200","1300","1400","1500","1600","1700","1800","1900","2000","2500","3000","3500" };

        Spinner s = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_min);

        s.setAdapter(adapter);
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                selItem = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable..make following changes in your code

String selected="";

public class MyItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

}

textView.setText(selected);

Comment: this won't work, my textView is now containing "" value no matter what the selected value of the spinner is

Answer (score 0):

**After register spinner ,you can get selected item from getSelectedItem() method on any action such ocClick()**

```
 regType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.regType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    regType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSave:

```
        intent.putExtra("regtype",regType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        startActivity(intent);  

            break;}}
```

Comment: I prefer not to click any button to get the value, I heard we can actually retrieve the value as fast as selecting the spinner