# How to retrieve spinner value from sharedpreferences? ANDROID

Tags: android, spinner, sharedpreferences

Hello I have a profile layout file wherein it saves the data the user inputs. This layout has checkboxes, textviews, and spinners. Then it will be viewed in my userprofile layout file as in textviews. I'm saving them to sharedpreferences. What I'd like to do is retrieve the String  value the user selected/saved from spinners, display it in a textview. How can I do this?

I'm wondering how to implement this:

```
 tvbloodtype.setText(prefs.getInt("bloodtype",0));
```

Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

I got error:

ResourcesNotFoundException: String resource ID

Comment: ResourcesNotFoundException: String Iresource ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use `String.valueOf()` or `Integer.toString()` for showing Integer in TextView . Example :

```
 tvbloodtype.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("bloodtype",0)));
```

**OR**

```
tvbloodtype.setText(Integer.toString(prefs.getInt("bloodtype",0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have your spinner object you can call yourSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener() to get the object that was selected. Then you can save your item in your TextView

```
yourSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parentview, View v, int position, long id) {
     curPos = position;
     String selected = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     tvbloodtype.setText(selected);
 }
```

});

Also reference: [How do you get the selected value of a Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner-android)

Answer (score 0):

write preferences like

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(key, value);  //key="YOUR_KEY_STRING" //value = your boolean value
editor.apply();
```

read from preferences

```
Boolean yourBoolean = prefs.getBoolean("YOUR_KEY_STRING",false); //false = value, if value wasn t set
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are saving your value to sharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("prf", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("bloodtype", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
edit.commit();
```

when you are retriving

```
tvbloodtype.setText(spinner.getString("bloodtype", ""));
```