# How to get values of the Spinners displayed in ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have been trying to solve this simple problem for two days now without success. I know a similar question have been asked before (like here:
[How do you get the selected value of a Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner/2652649#2652649) ), but I haven't been able to solve this yet.

So, I have created a simple app which contains a spinner and a custom ListView. The spinner (containing values 1,2,3,4,5..) creates more spinners (which contain Player names) to the ListView (eg. choosing 4 creates four spinners). Currently, the program works fine except that I don't know **how to get the selected values of the spinners in ListView when clicking a button in Action Bar?** I tried to use getItemAtPosition and getSelectedXXX() methods but I always tend to the get values from a single spinner I recently selected.

I am not sure do I have to invoke the methods in the Spinner's setOnItemSelectedListener(), or can I call the values from outside the SpinnerAdapter class.

Here is the custom Spinner class

```
public class PlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public PlayerAdapter(ArrayList<String> mPlayers) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, mPlayers);
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_players, null);
            }
            Spinner mSpinnerPlayer = (Spinner) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinner_player);

            ArrayAdapter<Player> spinnerAdapterPlayer = new ArrayAdapter<Player>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mPlayers);
        spinnerAdapterPlayer.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
            mSpinnerPlayer.setAdapter(spinnerAdapterPlayer);
            mSpinnerPlayer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Should I use getItemAtPosition or getSelectedXXX methods here?
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragment which inflates the layout creates the first spinner (sorry about the formatting and code style)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

//gets player names from a database, such as "Player 1", "Player 2" etc..
//this is container of the spinners displayed in the listview
    mPlayers = PlayerDB
            .get(getActivity())
            .getPlayers();

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, parent, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mSpinnerNumOfPlayers = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_numOfPlayers);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this.getActivity(),
                        R.array.numberOfPlayers_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        mSpinnerNumOfPlayers.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        mSpinnerNumOfPlayers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                String position = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                mArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                posInt = Integer.parseInt(position);

                 for (int i = 0; i < posInt; i++) {
                 mArray.add("" + i);
                 }

            PlayerAdapter adapter = new PlayerAdapter(mArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }   
                }       
        );

        return view;
    }
    // ActionBar
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_start:
        //when "start" button is clicked the spinner values are saved into an ArrayList
```

Comment: Same question was answered here


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I went through that question before, I but couldn't really associate it with my problem. In my case I have several widgets created into the listview, and I don't really know how I can get each spinner's values as they all share the "same" Spinner (in this case mSpinnerPlayer). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This method will retuns you the selected ite from the spinner..

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my problem is that I don't know how to implement that method for the several spinners in the ListView. In which part of the code I should invoke that and how do I get each spinners' value separately?